# Not receiving Stripe SCA authentication email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

Currently in the process of migrating a rails application to be Stripe SCA compliant. For the sake of simplicity, we opted for the stripe prebuilt tools where the client receives an email with a link that redirects the authentication to be completed on a Stripe self-host page. Despite having the 3DS customer emails toggled, the emails never get sent despite Stripe stating it has been sent:

> The invoice was finalized, but the customer needs to be complete 3D Secure authentication for the payment to succeed. This additional step is required by their bank to prevent fraud. Based on your settings, we've sent the customer an email with a link that visit to complete 3D secure.

Did anyone encounter similar behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mention you're in the process of migrating. Can I ask in which mode you're working in currently? Is that happening in test or live mode?

Comment: @v3nkman Only using test cards. I wondered about that since I am using a Stripe development account, however, I receive other emails on that account – subscription deletions, receipts.

Comment: So if the system you're testing is in test mode i.e. using a test secret key to interact with the API, then you should not be receiving any automated emails (i.e. the email that would be triggered when 3DS is required for a subscription payment) as they're not sent in test mode at all. Email sending _can_ be trigged manually from the dashboard by clicking on the receipt buttons on the payment page for example. Can you explain more about how you're receiving those emails taking this into account?

Comment: Each time I delete a subscription on my stripe development account I receive an email alerting the deletion. The same happens if I send a receipt from a successfully paid invoice. On both these scenarios, Stripe states its test data which leads me to believe that stripe does send emails on test envs.


I couldn't find that email sending you speak of, what I see is a payment page link on the details of the invoice that redirects to a SCA authentication page. Which in reality should probably be the same link that is included on the SCA email, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Thanks for the description on this. In order to move this forward can you please write in at https://support.stripe.com and include as much detail as possible. Thank you!

Comment: Any update on this? I'm running into the same issue trying to verify that Stripe is indeed sending out these 3D auth emails when payments fail.